# Why I am getting this message (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 405) in the root domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have written a web-based application using the ASP.NET 4.0 with Telerik Tool. Locally the application works great; everything works as expected as well as on the server running Windows Server 2008 R2 32-bit. When I move the app to IIS 7.5 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit, I faced the following error when I tried to browse the website using the following link:
    http://ServerName.AppName

[image]

However,  this issue was solved by pointing the address bar to the full URL (i.e.: "http://ServerName.AppName/Default.aspx"). But this is not a solution, because the application should be browsed without writing this part (default.aspx), So how to fix this problem?

And here's the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PMODServices;Integrated Security=True" name="PMODServicesConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <!--  <add assembly="office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>  -->
        <add assembly="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" validate="false" />
      <add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" validate="false" />
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
      <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
      <remove name="RadCompression" />
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
    <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
  </appSettings>
  <!-- I added the following to solve (asp.net ajax client-side framework failed to load) error that I especially faced on the Test Server only -->
  <location path="WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ScriptResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you setup default.aspx as default file on the target system?

Comment: I did not do it, because in all the applications that I developed I don't determined default.aspx as a default page. And when I browse any of these applications by writing the root domain, I will be redirected to the default page. Am I right? If not, could you please tell me how to setup it as a default file?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the default page configuration in your IIS server

Take a look at this article to setup your default page  in IIS

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439(WS.10).aspx

Alternateveley, if you just want to setup the default document for the current application:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <defaultDocument>
           <files>
               <add value="~/Default.aspx"/>
           </files>
       </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: I followed the link that you provided me with it and I am still facing the same problem. Also, I tried the code lines that you provided me with by adding them to the web.config file and I faced the following error: 403 - Forbidden: Access is Denied. And this is because of "~/" when I removed it, the system works but I am still getting the same error message mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

When I received this error, I removed the rad ajax panel (but kept the script manager). Once done, I was able to see where the errors were coming from. Once I fixed the errors, I added the rad ajax panel back and everything worked as intended.